# Question about proof of Krull principal ideal theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, local-rings

> How can we explain the following step in the [proof of Krull principal ideal theorem](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/31/4/401.extract): $l\{ ((z):x^n)/(z) \}$ or $l\{ ((x^n):z)/(x^n) \}$ is finite?

$l(M)$ - length of module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $I\subset R$ is an $M$-primary ideal then $R/I$ is artinian. In particular, every ideal $J/I$ if $R/I$ is an $R/I$-module of finite length, hence an $R$-module of finite length.

Comment: If $I\subset R$ is $M$-primary, why $R/I$ is artinian?

Comment: A prime ideal of $R/I$ is of the form $P/I$ with $I\subset P$. Then $M=\sqrt I\subset P$, so $P=M$. This shows that $R/I$ has Krull dimension zero.